# Use update model value inside jquery function in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a dropdownlist and I have to perform some task through jquery function after updating  the model . My ngmodel `([(ngModel)]="books")` is updated when change event of dropdownlist is triggerd.
but I am not getting the updated model `([(ngModel)]="books")`  value in jquery function. plz help I want to use updateed model value my jquery function. 
Here is my code

**html part:**

```
<select id="c1"   [(ngModel)]="book" name="book" (change)= "GetBook()" >
  <option *ngFor="let bk of book.bookdetails">{{bk.books}}</option>
</select>

<input  id="t1" name="book" type="text" [(ngModel)]="books">
```

Code in component part

**jquery function :**

```
$(document).on('change', '#c1', () => {
  var b1=  $('#t1').val();
});
```

**dropdown change function**

```
GetBook(){
  this.book.GetBook()
   .subscribe(response =>{
     this.books=response[0].Books
   });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get in you jQuery function ?  And what are you doing in `this.book.GetBook()`

Comment: if you just want to get the value of the input , why don't you use the ``(ngModelChange)`` on the ``<input>`` and do whatever you want with the value ?

Comment: @Rahul Swamynathan   this.book.GetBook()  is getting value from database and update my model  [(ngModel)]="books" and   after this functuon I want to use my update model value in jquery function to perform some  task . jquery function is lengthy so  I have written it in short form .Basically I need updated model value in my jquery function its my requirement.

Comment: @CruelEngine how to use (ngModelChange) plz I am new in angular .I am using angular 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything try to use *jQuery* by first add `jQuery` to `angular.json` file in `"scripts": [...]`.

To use *jQuery* this the most safely way to use *jQuery* I tried so far.

*TS*

```
....
declare let $: any;

@component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: ['...'],
  styleUrls: ['...']
})
export class JqueryExampleComponent implements onInit {

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const root = $(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
    root.find('#t1').on('change', function() {
      // Code
    });
  }
}
```

when you use `$(this.eleRef.nativeElement)` that gonna get the *tree root* of the `component` dom then `.find('...')` to get the element you want then use the *jQuery* `event` syntax like you always do.

**NOTE:** don't use *arrow function* `() => {...}` with *jQuery* syntax instead use *anonymous function* `function() {...}` where `arrow function` doesn't know `this` keyword and most of the *jQuery* script code based on OOP.

**Solution 1**

If you want to call `jquery function` after `GetBook()` *method* you can use `Observables` to achieve that.

*TS*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

declare let $: any;

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  isHidden = false;

  constructor(private eleRef: ElementRef) {}

  fun() {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      observer.next(
        this.book.GetBook().subscribe(response =>{
          this.books=response[0].Books
        });
      );
      observer.next(
        const root = $(this.eleRef.nativeElement);
        root.find('#c1').on('change', function() {
          let b1=  root.find('#t1').val();
        });
      );
    }).subscribe();
  }

}
```

*HTML*

```
<select id="c1" [(ngModel)]="book" name="book" (change)="fun()"></select>
```

**notice:** `fun()` not `GetBook()` on `change`

what is going to happen is when `select` *dropdown* `change` the `Observable` will execute the first `observer` which is `this.book.GetBook().subscribe(...)` then after will execute `jquery function` then *complete* the `Observable`

**Solution 2**

You can execute *jQuery* `function` inside `GetBook()` that supposed not executing *jQuery function* until `GetBook()` get executed and get the `subscribe` data... it should looks like that

```
GetBook() {
  this.book.GetBook().subscribe(response =>{
    this.books=response[0].Books;
    root.find('#c1').on('change', function() {
      let b1=  root.find('#t1').val();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Amir Fawzy  thanks for suggestion .but my problem is my jquery change() function is execute before the  GetBook()  function of  a dropdownlist so that I am not getting updated model value  . can we call jquery function after  triggering the  Getbook() function of dropdownlist.

Comment: I can get the updated model if I attache jquery change function with other control.but I need it to attache with dropdown list .so plz help me

Comment: Amir Fawzy still my jquery function is executing first  and also it is not getting updated model value

Comment: thanks for your valuable code but when I used    const root = $(this.eleRef.nativeElement); in my code it is giving me syntax error ..

Comment: you're welcome, try not put it in `const` variable like so `$(this.eleRef.nativeElement).find('#t1').on('change', function() {
      // Code
 });`
and make sure you add `jQuery` correctly to you project. and try to debug every part of your code separately to figure out which par may caused the issue.

Comment: its not working when I am including this code only angular component function is working jquery function is not working

Comment: Actually I dont know how jqury function will detect that Model has been updated .

Comment: Acually I have to change the color of the textboxes on the basis of the model  [(ngModel)]="books and  updatting the model from th function Getbook().
 I am  using  jquery function to change color of text box.
when I am  selecting  item first time from dropdownlist Getbook()  fun returning a value but 
my jquery function is not getting updated model value  and when I change the item from dropdownlist 
I am getting update model value which was for fist Item.

Comment: So my problem  is how to get updated model value in jquery function as I change the item from dropdownlist . if you have any other solution plz suggest me

Comment: is that what you want to achieve https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-input-on-select-cahnge?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Amir Fawzy  thanks you so much for giving me valuable code .But you are using ngclass  and I am using third party jquery library it is my project requirement. I have to change the color of textbox on basis of updated model [(ngModel)]="books in input control #t1 by using  jquery function . concept is same as you show me in your example .

Comment: Because I am new in angular I don't understand  why jquery does not get updated model value at that time when change event of dropdownlist get fires. I

Comment: @ Amir Fawzy thank u so much for your  suggestion and helping me . I was doing silly mistake  now I just wrote my jquery code  with  Getbook() method and  it is working .

Comment: you're welcome, happy to hear that you got the result you want ... and try to dig more in angular features `angular forms` one of them it's simplify such a case actually isn't best practice to use `jQuery` with `Angular`, *angular* alone as a framework has the power to achieve anything you want to implement in your project.